# YouTube API etag caching, etag refreshes on every request

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

First step:

I sent GET request

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key={API_KEY}&part=id&chart=mostPopular&regionCode=es&videoCategoryId=17&maxResults=25'
```

I received 200 OK response, body:

```
{
    "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
    "etag": "\"tnVOtk4NeGU6nDncDTE5m9SmuHc/CcRzMe1sxt_kvnG7LpS3dIQoCig\"",
    "nextPageToken": "CBkQAA",
    "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 181,
        "resultsPerPage": 25
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "etag": "\"tnVOtk4NeGU6nDncDTE5m9SmuHc/_GxV3cYD2wcterTfViCosiAVb54\"",
            "id": "LGnQfH8dnow"
        },
        {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "etag": "\"tnVOtk4NeGU6nDncDTE5m9SmuHc/-qYNOMCfpr8knbAS5auTTwRVt5Q\"",
            "id": "3cO8sTv9aE4"
        },
        {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "etag": "\"tnVOtk4NeGU6nDncDTE5m9SmuHc/4VBqB7u16yEkTMk6sSYEOI4P-hs\"",
            "id": "8-7b4Ixavrg"
        },
        {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "etag": "\"tnVOtk4NeGU6nDncDTE5m9SmuHc/ppyJEw0-OpZ3VI56IIn4vwl6Ja8\"",
            "id": "tZvxbUosFWw"
        },
        {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "etag": "\"tnVOtk4NeGU6nDncDTE5m9SmuHc/qk0x2ve66gTYW6_g8O4BWlfrvJU\"",
            "id": "_4-KEZw9bX4"
        },
        {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "etag": "\"tnVOtk4NeGU6nDncDTE5m9SmuHc/XP7oKSr0MwfURXwaW5nr1Qi8WbE\"",
            "id": "sgERdPX_dkM"
        },
        ...(other videos...)
    ]
}
```

I saved `body.etag` value in cache, on my side. This value: `"etag": "\"tnVOtk4NeGU6nDncDTE5m9SmuHc/CcRzMe1sxt_kvnG7LpS3dIQoCig\""`

I sent the same GET request one more time, but i added `If-None-Match: "tnVOtk4NeGU6nDncDTE5m9SmuHc/CcRzMe1sxt_kvnG7LpS3dIQoCig"` HTTP header to this GET request.

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key={API_KEY}&part=id&chart=mostPopular&regionCode=es&videoCategoryId=17&maxResults=25' \
--header 'If-None-Match: "tnVOtk4NeGU6nDncDTE5m9SmuHc/CcRzMe1sxt_kvnG7LpS3dIQoCig"'
```

I received 200 OK response, body:

```
{
    "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
    "etag": "\"tnVOtk4NeGU6nDncDTE5m9SmuHc/_ruxn7w4X-iRBUUok6BWY66DtLU\"",
    "nextPageToken": "CBkQAA",
    "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 181,
        "resultsPerPage": 25
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "etag": "\"tnVOtk4NeGU6nDncDTE5m9SmuHc/_GxV3cYD2wcterTfViCosiAVb54\"",
            "id": "LGnQfH8dnow"
        },
        {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "etag": "\"tnVOtk4NeGU6nDncDTE5m9SmuHc/-qYNOMCfpr8knbAS5auTTwRVt5Q\"",
            "id": "3cO8sTv9aE4"
        },
        {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "etag": "\"tnVOtk4NeGU6nDncDTE5m9SmuHc/4VBqB7u16yEkTMk6sSYEOI4P-hs\"",
            "id": "8-7b4Ixavrg"
        },
        {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "etag": "\"tnVOtk4NeGU6nDncDTE5m9SmuHc/ppyJEw0-OpZ3VI56IIn4vwl6Ja8\"",
            "id": "tZvxbUosFWw"
        },
        {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "etag": "\"tnVOtk4NeGU6nDncDTE5m9SmuHc/qk0x2ve66gTYW6_g8O4BWlfrvJU\"",
            "id": "_4-KEZw9bX4"
        },
        {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "etag": "\"tnVOtk4NeGU6nDncDTE5m9SmuHc/XP7oKSr0MwfURXwaW5nr1Qi8WbE\"",
            "id": "sgERdPX_dkM"
        },
        ...(other videos...)
    ]
}
```

I expect to receive 304 not modified, not 200 OK and the same result.
But i still to receive 200 OK and new etag in response body. See the screenshoot.

[image: difference between responses]

I expect to have only one first response. I expect to receive 304 when i request the same query with `If-None-Match: "tnVOtk4NeGU6nDncDTE5m9SmuHc/CcRzMe1sxt_kvnG7LpS3dIQoCig"` cause no changes in requested data.

Comment: Sorry, may be i don't understand something in this doc, but i read it here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#etags is it works in another way? Does the etag in root of response body (or in response headers) describe youtube#VideoListResponse? Is there a way to cache this query via etag?

Comment: Please clearly define your problem:  Do you not get the expected ETAG or the expected HTTP response code? The current question is ambiguous. Please include the exact GET request made in order to request the 25 most popular videos as you have stated, including headers. THE QUESTION IS NOT CLEAR.

Comment: Hello, i have edited the question. Is it  clear now? Thanks you!

Comment: the question is clear now.

Comment: Do you know the reason of this behavior?